# How to prevent UILabel to fill the entire screen?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I am trying to display a `UILabel` that may take up multiple lines but I'm having problem with how the height is resized.

Here is what it looks when I have text over a single line, displaying correctly:

[image]

When the text spans multiple lines however this happens:

[image]

Here's the interface builder settings I'm using:

[image]

Ideally I'd like the text view to remain at athe top of the screen and just take up as much space as it needs to diaplay the text but I really can't tell where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The text view is a bit tricky to handle with automatic layout. If possible use an `UILabel`. If not then there are several issues with the text view and the most manageable solution is to add the height constraint which is then manipulated in the code.

The height of the text view content can be determined as:

```
let height = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size).height
```

It is also possible to use

```
let height = textView.contentSize.height
```

But the results are sometimes incorrect.

You do need to then set the delegate for the text view so that on change you will refresh the size of the text view.

Comment: What do I do with that size once I have it? Setting a new frame to the UILabel does nothing.

Comment: Sorry, this was meant for the UITextView. Your issue must be somewhere else. As for the usage of this you need an outlet to the height constraint of the text view and set its constant to the value of retrieved height.

Answer (score 0):

Well you did give it permission to do so based on your constraints.  Any height > 0 as long as it's 20 from the top margin.  Since you don't have any other views to base your height off of you can hook up an outlet to your label and use this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    label.sizeToFit()
}
```

Comment: The label already does that by itself. It has a content hugging priority which should be set to 251 by default. It means that if no constraint is set to restrict the size then it will shrink as much as its content (text) allows. The problem is using a text view like this.

Comment: I set up constraints as in his example and ran this code.  It fixes the issue.  Also, the OP is asking about UILabel, not UITextView.

Comment: That did not fix the issue for me. Neither calling sizeToFit() nor setting the label's frame programmatically.

Comment: @Frankie My bad. Actually this should work. There must be another another thing that is wrong here overall.

Comment: @spacitron Is the outlet hooked up correctly?  If you are setting the text programmatically, are you calling sizeToFit *after* setting the text?

Comment: @Frankie yes, I'm calling it after. I also tried setting a height constraints and setting it to 50 but that also does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uncheck the "Preferred Width" explicit checkbox(In Size Inspector)
2. Remove the height constraint on you UILabel.

It will definitely work.